# Authenticate via POP3 using vPopMail

Tags: email, imap, qmail

I'm working on installing vPopMail on CentOS for use with a Qmail / Courier-IMAP mail-server setup. So far, everything is working out well enough. Mail sent to any virtual user I have setup under any virtual domain (assuming MX records are pointed correctly in the domain DNS) I add to vPopMail is routed correctly to the vPopMail ./Maildir/ and is viewable in /home/vpopmail/domains/domain-example.com/user.name/Maildir/new.

The problem I'm having now is telling the pop service to authenticate using vPopMail instead of the ~default~ Qmail / Courier-IMAP authentication method(s).

"You also need to modify your pop server startup line to use the vchkpw program for authentication." (found at http://www.inter7.com/vpopmail/vpopmail.html) is all I can find in any documentation to even give me the clue that that needs to be done.

So, the question:

How do I tell my pop server to authenticate with vPopMail?

Thanks so much in advance! :)

(Feel free to let me know what (if) more info is needed to answer my question..)

Answer (score 1):

Id go ahead and check this out
http://www.inter7.com/vpopmail/install.txt

namely item 12

then go ahead and add those lines to your rc.local file or rc.sysinit

good luck

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Unfortunately this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Although, it should be mentioned that that does seem to be the correct direction.. Those specific instructions, however, didn't do the trick.

Also, I don't seem to have the tcpserver file anywhere on my system.. Could this be a problem?

Comment: try something like this maybe? 

/usr/local/bin/tcpserver H-R-V-1 100-c 0-t 1-x-p-u QMAILDUID /etc/qmail/tcp.smtp.cdb NOFILESGID 0 g | /usr/local/qmail/bin/splogger & SMTP /usr/local/qmail/bin/qmail-smtpd /home/vpopmail/bin/vchkpw /usr/bin/true

Comment: Also check out this page: http://www.lslnet.com/linux/edosc/22/linux-22201018.htm ... it has some information about virtual domain virtual mail users